# Extract variables with specific names and loop for all files

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

The aim is to (1) extract variables (columns) with specific names (2) loop for all files in the folder and (3) save the output in csv files.

For example, the data look like for one file:

```
structure(list(frame = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), g_1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 
0, 0), g_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), xy_1 = c(0.4, 0.43, 0.32, 0.33, 
0.39), xy_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1), unit_1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    unit_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), unit_3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), .Names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)
```

For each dataset, I only need the variables (1) frame and (2) those starting with "unit_". So the output I need to get and save in csv for each file looks like:

```
╔═══════╦════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ frame ║ unit_1 ║ unit_2 ║ unit_3 ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1.00 ║  1.00  ║   .00  ║   .00  ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  2.00 ║  1.00  ║   .00  ║   .00  ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  3.00 ║  1.00  ║   .00  ║   .00  ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  4.00 ║  1.00  ║   .00  ║   .00  ║
╠═══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╣
║  5.00 ║  1.00  ║   .00  ║   .00  ║
╚═══════╩════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using *dplyr* or others.

I was thinking of:

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/files", pattern="csv")
out <- lapply(files, function(file) {
  dat <- data.frame(fread(paste0("C:/files/", file) ) ) 
  dat <- dat[c("frame", "unit_1", "unit_2", "unit_3")]})
```

From here, I was not clear how to save each file into csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `select` with `select_helpers` like `starts_with`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     select(frame, starts_with('unit'))
```

-output

```
#   frame unit_1 unit_2 unit_3
#1     1      1      0      0
#2     2      1      0      0
#3     3      1      0      0
#4     4      1      0      0
#5     5      1      0      0
```

Or a regex in `matches` to match the pattern that starts (`^`) with the substring 'unit' followed by a `_` and one or more digits (`\\d+`) at the end (`$`) of the string as column names

```
df1 %>%
      select(frame, matches('^unit_\\d+$'))
```

---

If it is a `list` of data.frame, loop over the `list` with `map/walk`, read the files with `read_csv`, select the columns of interest and create new files in the same directory with prefix 'new_' using `write_csv`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
walk(files, ~ read_csv(file.path("C:/files", .x)) %>%
               select(frame, starts_with('unit')) %>%
               write_csv(file.path("C:/files", str_c("new_", .x)))
       )
```

---

The equivalent option in `base R` is `startsWith`

```
subset(df1, select = c('frame',
          names(df1)[startsWith(names(df1), 'unit')]))
```

Or with `grep`

```
subset(df1, select = grep('^(frame|unit)', names(df1), value = TRUE))
```

and for the `list` of files

```
lapply(files, function(x) {
      tmp <-  subset(read.csv(file.path("C:/files", x)),
              select = grep('^(frame|unit)', names(df1), value = TRUE))
    write.csv(tmp, file.path("C:/files", paste0("new_", x)), 
                 row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun I will incorporate your dplyr code; could you also take a look at the last line of code I wrote? I was wondering what would be a good way to save each file stored in 'out' to be saved in csv..

Comment: @user14250906 do you need to save it as new files or updated old files

Comment: Right, as new files! By the way, your codes are really awesome; this should be something that more people should know about!

Comment: @user14250906 updated the code with `walk` please check

Comment: Wow, using walk is super efficient. Thank you..!